# Is there a technical name for this concept of parsing a string with sizes?

Tags: string, list, delphi, packet

I came up with a technique a while back which I've been using in multiple projects. It's using a single string to store a list of values. Each value is prefixed with the size of the value, then the deliminator (after size) and then the data - and repeat. Using this technique means that you can store literally any type of character, without trying to exclude the use of a deliminator between the values.

Here's a sample of such a string:

`23|This is the first value13|Another value5|third`

That translates to a list of these values:

- This is the first value
- Another value
- third

I've learned by testing that this method (along with my functions to convert between this string and either an array or string list) is very fast while keeping minimal memory. It's also very useful for sending data packets (which is where I first came up with this method).

Is there a technical name for this? Parsing is too broad of a word in this case, there must be a more specific term.

Comment: I use this method primarily in a custom socket set of mine (TCP Server/Client components) - rather than waiting for an OnData event and reading raw data from the buffer, I have an event type `TJDPacketEvent = procedure(Sender: TJDRawSocket; const Cmd: Integer; const Data: Array of String) of object;` and that `Data: Array of String` is derived from the single string as posted above

Comment: Cmd = integer representing a command, service, or whatnot, and Data = a list of whatever parameters are to be associated with the Command (Cmd).

Comment: Technical term is "inventing a little language".  Or reinventing the wheel. Or "failing to use JSON". Or "custom pickling". You're packing multiple fields, a record of field values, into a single string. I'd call that "pickling".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of standard/established types of serialization, the closest that I'm familiar with is [type-length-value (TLV) encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value), which differs from your scheme in that it supports the use of non-fixed types, whereas yours would require the type of each field to be known in advance (and indeed, you seem to use only strings, in all fields).

Comment: I've been pondering the idea of passing along the type of data along with, but one main point of my structure is for minimal memory, and also whatever is using this method (in my shared unit) is responsible to know its own types anyway and have to do the conversions manually.

Comment: and technically speaking, my encoding would then be called length-value (LV) encoding because I don't have the type

Comment: Well, you're already using a byte to separate the length from the value; you could always co-opt that byte to also represent type; that is, instead of pipe, you could use `S` for strings, `I` for integers, and so on, and thereby support a small number of types. Better yet, if you use dedicated codes for individual fields, you can detect mismatches during deserialization, rather than potentially read wrong data without realizing it (if there's a discrepancy between sender and receiver).

Comment: I don't know if the term "LV encoding" is in use for such a thing, but sure, works for me. :-)

Comment: So then that would be length-type-value (LTV) encoding :P

Answer (score 4):

The FORTRAN language's syntax had *[Hollerith constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollerith_constant)*, sometimes called *Hollerith strings*. They are identical to your example other than using the letter `H` instead of `|`.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [marshalling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: -1: Marshalling is a much more general concept than this specific encoding.

Comment: @KevinReid (and the other downvoter): Please reread the first two sentences of the question. It's not obvious to me that the OP was asking about this specific encoding, as opposed to the concept in general (as illustrated/exemplified by this specific encoding). I went with the former interpretation, vanza went with the latter; but I think both interpretations are valid, and neither warrants a downvote!

Comment: @ruakh Have a look at the title of the question. I am confident the OP meant to ask specifically about using string lengths (as opposed to some delimiter character potentially requiring escaping).

Comment: Yes, the trick of this concept is that you don't have to worry about risking accidentally using the deliminator inside one of the strings. If it was plain deliminated values, then you'd have to have a special mechanism to avoid using the deliminator somewhere in the value. In my example, you can use any character in the data, including the deliminator, as much as you want. I was wanting the specific pinpointed method.

Comment: I *love* when discussions go into semantic territory... but I replied with a generic term because the original question doesn't make it explicit it's talking about the specific approach, and rather tries to use a very generic term ("parsing") to describe it; since it also doesn't mention marshalling / serialization, it's not that much of a leap of faith to think the generic mechanism was in question.

Answer (score -1):

Doing this generic type of data handling has been around as long as computer science itself.  It goes by different names, but the idea of it all has to do with the ability to handle larger amounts of data at once for efficiency-sake (usually increasing speed via less disk i-o).  Notable examples within Delphi include TMemo.Text and even before Delphi, the TEXT or TEXTFILE type within Turbo/Borland Pascal.  Behind the scenes, this type pulls back "text data" and then parses it out in such a manner as you are describing.  As a stream (the way files are processed anyway), standard Windows text files have #13#10 as delimiters, which can be parsed to determine where string breaks occur in text.

Comment: -1. The question asked for what this technique is called. This answer says there are many names for it, but doesn't tell what any of them are, so it hasn't really answered the question. Furthermore, the examples you give do not resemble the technique demonstrated in the question. There are no length indicators in ordinary text files.

Comment: Plus I don't usually use this while writing to files anyway, but through socket streaming.