# Is this an encoding technique?

Tags: delphi, encoding, tlv

Furhter to [ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh)'s post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8379433/744588), I want to ascertain wether the following snippet falls into the [TLV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value) or [KLV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KLV) encoding type :

```
interface

const
  Lex_0: string[length('(EOF)')] ='(EOF)';
  Lex_1: string[length('(Error)')] ='(Error)';

  LexTable : array[0..114] of ^String = (
  @Lex_0,
  @Lex_1
  )
```

Comment: What you're showing is no encoding at all, it's just the definition of  some constants.

Comment: What this falls into is the non-type-safe-code category. You've declared an array of pointers to long strings, but you've stored pointers to other heterogeneous string types. Even if you've disabled long strings (which I think would be foolish), they're still pointing to short strings with lengths different from what the array says they are.

Comment: What does this have to do with the Gold parser?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: This snippet is taken from a code grabed from the Gold Parser site. Such details was stripped off due to further edit of the question. It's has even qualified as "clumsy" by it's author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample code won't work, as you are mixing `shortstring const` and `pointer` of `string` - as Rob stated in his comment.

And your code has nothing to do with KLV nor TLV encoding.

Here may be a sample of TLV encoding (I show only string encoding, but you can add other types):

```
type
  TTLVType = (tlvUnknown, tlvString, tlvInteger);

function EncodeToTLV(const aString: WideString): TBytes;
var Len: integer;
begin
  Len := length(aString)*2;
  SetLength(result,Len+sizeof(TTLVType)+sizeof(integer));
  Result[0] := ord(tlvString); // Type
  PInteger(@Result[sizeof(TTLVType)])^ := Len; // Length
  move(pointer(aString)^,Result[sizeof(TTLVType)+sizeof(integer)],Len); // Value
end;

function DecodeStringFromTLV(const aValue: TBytes): WideString;
begin
  if (length(aValue)<3) or (aValue[0]<>ord(tlvString)) or
     (PInteger(@aValue[sizeof(TTLVType)])^<>length(aValue)-sizeof(TTLVType)-sizeof(integer)) then
    raise EXception.Create('Invalid input format');
  SetString(result,PWideChar(@Result[sizeof(TTLVType)+sizeof(integer)]),PInteger(@aValue[sizeof(TTLVType)])^ div 2);
end;
```

I used `WideString` here because it can safely store any Unicode content, even on pre-Delphi 2009 version of the compiler.

You may use a record instead of my pointer arithmetic:

```
type
  TTLVHeader = packed record
    ContentType: TTLVType;
    ContentLength: integer;
    Content: array[0..1000] of byte; // but real length will vary
  end;
  PTLVHeader = ^TTLVHeader;

function EncodeToTLV(const aString: WideString): TBytes;
var Len: integer;
begin
  Len := length(aString)*2;
  SetLength(result,Len+sizeof(TTLVType)+sizeof(integer));
  with PTLVHeader(result)^ do 
  begin
    ContentType := tlvString;
    ContentLength := Len;
    move(pointer(aString)^,Content,Len); 
  end;  
end;
```

A similar encoding may be used for KLV, but adding an integer key in the header.

Comment: Thank you. (Très instructive, merci bien).

Besides, you can find [here](http://goldparser.org/grammars/files/Delphi-7_v11.zip) the project from which I've grabbed the snippet. I tested it under D2007 and it works.

Comment: @menjaraz Your code snippet won't even compile. A ^string is not a ^shortstring (since Delphi 1). This code may work if it type cast it back to a ^shortstring before use, or rely on the shortstring layout.

Comment: You are quite right. The snippet is not complete in itself and I didn't make myself understood. When I said it works, I mean the original project as a whole, from which I stripped it. Some type cast was used actually.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this only defines two constants (`Lex_0` and `Lex_1` in this case) and puts them into an array called `LexTable`, this is no encoding at all.

```
Lex_0: string // declares a string constant by the name of Lex_0
[length('(EOF)')] // specifies the length of the string, this is equivalent to [5] in this case
='(EOF)' // sets the constant to '(EOF)'
```

then the `LexTable` array of pointers to string is created and addresses of the two constants are put in the array.

Comment: The snippet is an excrept of some parser generated code from a grammar and template as input. The tool doesn't have extensive capability of evaluating string length (lexeme in the falling case). Hardcoding it was just a workaround, I believe.